# Vue material add modal button in a table for each row

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, vuejs2

I have this code in vue that is a table with the component "vue materials" and what I try to do is that for row of the table I put a button that launches me a modal, for that I have this code but it does not do anything to me

```html
    <md-table v-model="payslips" md-sort="created_at" md-sort-order="asc" md-card md-fixed-header>
      <md-table-row slot="md-table-row" slot-scope="{ item }">
        <md-table-cell md-label="User" md-sort-by="alias">{{ item.user.name }}</md-table-cell>
        <md-table-cell md-label=""><md-button class="md-raised" @click.native="downloadFile(item.id,false)" >Show</md-button></md-table-cell>

        <md-table-cell md-label="">
            <md-dialog-confirm :md-active.sync="active" md-title="Use Google's location service?" md-content="Let Google help apps determine location.
             <br> This means sending <strong>anonymous</strong> location data to Google, even when no apps are running." md-confirm-text="Agree"
              md-cancel-text="Disagree" @md-cancel="onCancel" @md-confirm="onConfirm" />
            <md-button class="md-primary md-raised" @click="active = true">Delete</md-button>
        </md-table-cell>

      </md-table-row>
    </md-table>
```

On method I have this code

```js
    onConfirm: function onConfirm() {
      console.log(this.value);
    },
    onCancel: function onCancel() {
      console.log(this.value);
    }
```

Comment: Before anything, tell what version of vue material you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this - you don't need to add the function name just before the ()'s

```js
    onConfirm: function () {
      console.log(this.value);
    },
    onCancel: function () {
      console.log(this.value);
    }
```

Alternatively, you could use an even simpler syntax

```js
    onConfirm () {
      console.log(this.value);
    },
    onCancel () {
      console.log(this.value);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer I have already corrected it in my code but the problem is still the same, I do not get the modal when I press the button

Comment: Have you tried using `@click.native` on all your click events?

Comment: Also, I would put your modal on the save level as the table (i.e. take it out of the table cell). The button only needs to reference the modal in order to make it appear - and this could be adding to your issue.